# uninitialized constant CommentsController::Comments - Rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have just made a new model named `Comments` and now I'm trying to make a view so that user can leave comments from the UI(very basic stuff here). But, I'm running into this error `uninitialized constant CommentsController::Comments` for the life of me I can't figure out why it's throwing this error and not just rendering the page when it's clicked? 
I'm going to post all the applicable code and error for clarity.

MODEL:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :subscriber 
end
```

CONTROLLER:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 def new
  @comments = Comments.new
 end
end
```

ROUTES

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users
resources :subscribers, except: :show
resources :comments
```

SCHEMA:

```
 create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "description"
   t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
   t.string   "fav_drink"
   t.string   "visit_time"
 end
```

VIEW:

```
 <h2>Let us get to know you more <%= link_to 'Comment', new_comment_path %> </h2>
```

This is the link I've set up to click the the page where the user will leave a comment.

ERROR:

[image]

Let me know if you need to see anymore code. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't your model named  `Comment`? without `s`?

Comment: I believe it has the `s` I'll post the schema in a edit

Comment: Not the table, the model class itself. ActiveRecord uses singular names for models `class Comment`.

Comment: I posted the model class also. It's a singular name

Comment: Exactly, `Comment.new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made a silly mistake and called `Comments.new` instead of `Comment.new`

Answer (score 0):

Models are referenced singularly as they are classes. You have made a mistake of `Comments.new` but it should be `Comment.new`.